# How to get a tensor symbol like this?

Tags: symbols, tensor

[image]

As you can see, it looks like the superposition of two `\rightharpoonup`.
I don't know how to make it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: i don't believe this is in unicode.  if you can provide a specific reference where it appears in a published book or journal, i will submit it for consideration.

Answer (score 6):

Not very beautiful, as the kerning looks different for different symbols (the double harpoon gets shorter or longer for other symbols below). But if you just need it ones, it doesn't matter. Or you define it for each symbol with different magnitude of kerning.
[image]

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf} % optional to get something close to your "T"   
\newcommand{\doubleTensor}[1]{\mathrlap{\mkern-1.5mu\rightharpoonaccent{\phantom{#1}}}\rightharpoonaccent{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[\doubleTensor{\mscrT}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: More beautiful than mine ;-)

Comment: Thanks, @karlkoeller. In LaTeX everything looks beautiful if printed super huge :-) But the differing width for different symbols is annoying me. Can't find a better solution. Best way would be to redefine the `\rightharpoonaccent` with a fixed kerning and maybe cropped on the left, but that's out of my league

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\doublerightharpoonup}{%
  \rightharpoonup\mkern-10mu\rightharpoonup%
}

\begin{document}

\[\overset{\doublerightharpoonup}{T}\]

\end{document}
```